# Total for columns in a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to calculate the totals for a series of columns in a table, how do I go about doing this?

Here is a sample of the data I want to sum:

```
array:1 [
  "traders" => array:6 [
    "Jim Mayor__targeted_target" => array:2 [
      "amounts" => array:13 [
        0 => 5
        1 => 5
        2 => 0
        3 => 0
        4 => 0
        5 => 0
        6 => 0
        7 => 0
        8 => 0
        9 => 0
        10 => 0
        11 => 0
      ]
      "row_name" => "Targeted target"
    ]
    "Jim Mayor__actual_targeted" => array:2 [
      "amounts" => array:13 [
        0 => 0
        1 => 1
        2 => 0
        3 => 0
        4 => 0
        5 => 0
        6 => 1
        7 => 1
        8 => 0
        9 => 0
        10 => 0
        11 => 0
      ]
      "row_name" => "Actual targeted"
    ]
    "Bob Martinez__targeted_target" => array:2 [
      "amounts" => array:13 [
        0 => 1
        1 => 0
        2 => 0
        3 => 0
        4 => 0
        5 => 0
        6 => 0
        7 => 0
        8 => 0
        9 => 0
        10 => 0
        11 => 0
      ]
      "row_name" => "Targeted target"
    ]
    "Bob Martinez__actual_targeted" => array:2 [
      "amounts" => array:13 [
        0 => 19
        1 => 45
        2 => 20
        3 => 26
        4 => 21
        5 => 10
        6 => 12
        7 => 20
        8 => 11
        9 => 2
        10 => 0
        11 => 0
      ]
      "row_name" => "Actual targeted"
    ]
...
```

I want to sum together each index, e.g. for Jim Mayor__targeted_target, index 0 added to index 0 of Bob Martinez__targeted_target (this gives the total for January). It needs to work with an unlimited number of traders.

The function that generates the data:

```
protected function addRow($func, $params, $data, $year, $traderName, $rowName, $type, $image = null, $format = null, $underline = false)
    {
        $date = Carbon::createFromDate($year, 4, 1);
        $total = 0;
        $traderName = $traderName . '__' . str_replace(' ', '_', strtolower($rowName));
        for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
            $params[1] = $date->year;
            $params[2] = $date->month;
            $result = call_user_func_array($func, $params);
            $data['traders'][$traderName]['amounts'][] = $result ? $result : 0;
            $total += $result;
            $date->addMonth();
        }
        $data['traders'][$traderName]['amounts'][] = $total;
        $data['traders'][$traderName]['row_name'] = $rowName;
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go over your data and save results in an additional array:

```
$results = array();

foreach ($traders as $trader) {
    foreach ($trader['amounts'] as $i => $amount) {
        if (!isset($results[$i])) {
            $results[$i] = 0;
        }

        $results[$i] += $amount;
    }
}
```

The result array will contains the sums of all traders.

*Not tested but should work.*

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
function sumRowsByMonth($traders)
{
    $sums = array_fill(0, 12, 0);
    foreach($traders as $trader) {
        foreach($trader['amounts'] as $monthId => $amount) {
            $sums[$monthId] += $amount;
        }
    }
    return $sums;
}
```

I tested with this:

```
$arr = array(
    'traders' => array(
        'Jim Mayor__targeted_target' => array(
            'amounts' => array(
                0  => 5,
                1  => 5,
                2  => 0,
                3  => 0,
                4  => 0,
                5  => 0,
                6  => 0,
                7  => 0,
                8  => 0,
                9  => 0,
                10 => 0,
                11 => 0,
            )
        ),
        'Bob Martinez__targeted_target' => array(
            'amounts' => array(
                0  => 19,
                1  => 45,
                2  => 20,
                3  => 26,
                4  => 21,
                5  => 10,
                6  => 12,
                7  => 20,
                8  => 11,
                9  => 2,
                10 => 0,
                11 => 0,
            )
        ),
    ),
);
var_dump(sumRowsByMonth($arr['traders']));
```

Comment: The main problem I keep getting that it is summing all rows, including actual_targeted. actual_targeted needs to be grouped and summed separately to targeted_target.

Comment: I sent another answer using strstr.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) function.

> `array_sum()` returns the sum of values in an array

Also, you said you want to count `targeted target` and `actual targeted` separately.

```
$actual = [];
$targeted = [];

foreach ($traders as $trader) {
    $sum = array_sum($trader['anmounts']);
    $trader['row_name'] === 'Actual targeted') ? $actual += $sum : $target += $sum;
}
```

Maybe you'll need to modify this a little bit to tune behavior, but I guess I got the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the name is also dynamic, so 'Actual targeted' can be anything.

Comment: @imperium2335 add some static flag to the array.

Answer (score 0):

@imperium2335:

> The main problem I keep getting that it is summing all rows, including actual_targeted. actual_targeted needs to be grouped and summed separately to targeted_target.

Then do this:

```
function sumRowsByMonth($traders)
{
    $sums = array();

    foreach($traders as $traderName => $trader) {
        $type = strstr($traderName, '__');
        if( empty($sums[$type]) ) {
            $sums[$type] = array_fill(0, 12, 0);
        }

        foreach($trader['amounts'] as $monthId => $amount) {
            $sums[$type][$monthId] += $amount;
        }
    }
    return $sums;
}
```

Read this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php